# Download prestashop product, updated after certain date, using API

Tags: date, filter, prestashop, product

Download Prestashop product using API which are created or updated after certain date.

Is there any filter for that? How to use it?

I was trying with filter in the API parameter, but can't get the answer.
I want to download the products which were created or updated on the Presashop store after a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'filter' parameter to filter products or orders based on their creation or update dates. I was able to reproduce this using PrestaShop 1.7.8.10.

For example to filter all the products with `date_upd` greater than 2023-10-10 00:00:00, you need to call:
`/api/products?display=full&filter[date_upd]=>[2023-10-10 00:00:00]&date=1`

To filter all the products with `date_add` smaller than 2017-11-15 13:51:06, you need to call:
`/api/products?display=full&filter[date_upd]=<[2017-11-15 13:51:06]&date=1`

The important thing to note here is to include the `data=1` parameter. Otherwise, the `WebserviceRequestCore` class will remove `date_upd` and `date_add` from the available filters, as stated on [line 1135](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/e7a1e3e7cd8be3bc7a023b3c03c3bdd51ea4f1dc/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php#L1135).